# PayWay error: Invalid IP address

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-services

I am using PayWay payment gateway and Westpac banking services for our Australian client. I am developing its code and initial testing in India location. As per `PayWay Net Developer's Guide` I have writen all code as per given. Now I am trying to paying testing amount at that time it gives us an error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid IP address
```

How to resolve this error and why it occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a security measure, PayWay only accepts token requests from IP addresses that you nominate.

That error indicates your token request is coming from an IP address that is not in the list.  You can add your server's IP to the list by:-

- Sign-in to PayWay
- Click on **Setup Net**
- Choose **Shopping Cart** as your integration type
- Click **Next** until you reach teh security page (shown below)
- Enter the external IP address of the server that is sending the token request

You can enter multiple IP addresses and specify a subnet if needed.

[image: PayWay Net Security Page]